# Is it Possible to Prove that the von Neumann Universe with Atoms Contains Every Set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading Herbert Enderton's *Elements of Set Theory*.

In Chapter One in a section titled, "Sets--An Informal View", Enderton constructs a hierarchy of sets. He starts with the set of atoms $A$ and puts this as the 'base' of his hierarchy:

$V_0:=A$

Then Enderton defines recursively successive levels of his hierarchy. For $n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$V_{n+1}:=V_n\cup\mathscr{P}V_n$

Then Enderton notes that infinite sets like $\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\},\ldots\}$ do not appear at any level in his hierarchy. He therefore defines

$V_{\omega}:=V_0\cup V_1\cup V_2\ldots$

and continues the hierarchy:

$V_{\alpha +1}=V_{\alpha}\cup\mathscr{P}V_{\alpha}$

where $\alpha$ is any one of these new ordinal numbers.

Then Enderton has a remark (page eight):

> A fundamental principle is the following: Every set appears somewhere in this hierarchy. That is, for every set $a$ there is some $\alpha$ with $a\in V_{\alpha +1}$. That is what sets are; they are the members of the levels of our hierarchy.

---

I understand that one can postulate that nothing is a set unless it appears in this hierarchy, as Enderton's final remark suggests. However, one already has already accepted the existence of various sets (the empty set, unions and power sets) to reach this construction, so it seems possible one could build a set that is not in the hierarchy.

Is it possible to prove that any set whose elements are atoms or sets of (sets of sets of....) atoms appears in the hierarchy?

Comment: The theorem $\forall x\exists\alpha(x\in V_\alpha)$ follows from the axiom of foundation IIRC, maybe the proof of that theorem from foundation can be modified for $V$ to have a different base case (namely $A$)?

Comment: "any set whose elements are atoms or sets of (sets of sets of....) atoms": Can you define the class of such sets more rigorously?

Comment: Enderton gives us the set of atoms A and the empty set $\varnothing$, and we have been able to form more sets from those with various combinations of the union operation and the power set operation. The answer to your question is "no", I don't know how to specify an arbitrary member of that class. If I could, I think a proof could follow quickly.

Comment: You have to survey the various "operations" defined by axioms: consider e.g. Separation. If we apply it to a set belonging to $V_n$, every new set produced by Separation will be an element of $\mathscr P(V_n)$.

Comment: Certainly I will eventually survey the axiom schema of separation and other axioms. However, Enderton has not introduced any of that yet. So does the statement "every set appears somewhere in this hierarchy" require proof via yet-unspecifed axioms, or is this a definition as in the final statement ("That is what sets are; they are the members of the levels of our hierarchy.")?